# Any Easier way to integrate:$\iint\limits_D{e^{x+y}}d\sigma,D=\{\left . (x,y) \right ||x|+|y|\leqslant1\}$

Tags: calculus, integration

This is my way:
\begin{align}
    \iint\limits_D{e^{x+y}}d\sigma 
    & = \int_{-1}^0e^xdx\int_{-x-1}^{x+1}e^ydy + \int_0^1e^xdx\int_{x-1}^{-x+1}e^ydy \\
    & = \cdots \\
    & = e-e^{-1}
\end{align}

A little complicated.
Any help will be appreciated

Comment: That looks like the unit circle,  so you might want to switch to polar.

Comment: ^It's the unit circle in the $1$-norm, so its actually a square with vertices $(1,0)$, $(0,1)$, $(-1,0)$, and $(0,-1)$.

Comment: Your solution looks easy enough to me. Not sure if there's "easier".

Answer (score 3):

You may apply [Coordinate Rotation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_(mathematics))  to simplify the process:

\begin{align}
\iint\limits_D{e^{x+y}}d\sigma \mathrel{\mathop{\xrightarrow[u=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}(x+y)]{v=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}(x-y)}}}\int_{-\frac{1}{\sqrt2}}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt2}}dv\int_{-\frac{1}{\sqrt2}}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt2}}e^{\sqrt2u}du=\left[ e^{\sqrt2u} \right]_{-\frac{1}{\sqrt2}}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt2}}=e-e^{-1}
\end{align}

You may also transform like this:
$$\left\{ \matrix{
  v = x - y  \cr 
  u = x + y  \cr}  \right.$$
And note the Jacobian determinant is equal to $\frac{1}{2}$ instead of 1
[image: Coordinate Rotation]